# std::vector and its iterator as single template typename

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

In order to get an "easier-to-remember" interface to the
index-generating function std::distance(a,b), I came up 
with the idea of a better distinction of it's arguments 
(when used against the base of a vector: vec.begin() )
by calling a templated function with the vector
and its iterator, like:

```
std::vector<MyType> vect;
std::vector<MyType>::const_iterator iter;
...
...
size_t id = vectorindex_of(iter, vect);
```

with the rationale of never confusing the order of
the arguments ;-)

The explicit formulation of the above idea would
read sth. like

```
 template <typename T>
 inline 
 size_t vectorindex_of( 
          typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator iter, 
          const std::vector<T>& vect ) {

  return std::distance( vect.begin(), iter ); 
 }
```

... which works but looks awkward.

I'd love to have the template mechanism implicitly deduce the types
like (pseudo-code):

```
 template <typename T>
 inline 
 size_t vectorindex_of(T::const_iterator iter, const T& vect) {
    return std::distance( vect.begin(), iter ); 
 }
```

... which doesn't work. But why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fix is easy: add `typename` before `T::const_iterator iter`.  This is needed because class templates may be specialized and using `typename` tells the compiler a type name is expected at `T::const_iterator` and not a value or something.

You do the same in your less generic function, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
 template <typename T>
 inline 
 std::size_t vectorindex_of(typename T::const_iterator iter, const T& vect) {
    return std::distance( vect.begin(), iter ); 
 }
```

Should work fine (notice the `typename`). Template arguments should be deduced in either case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this simple fix. I'd like to tag both of your answers as "accepted answer", but only one is possible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in the "easier-to-remember" way to get the index of a vector iterator:

i - vec.begin()

It's identical to pointer arithmetic with random access iterators!